# dir-pagination directive angularjs : Update pagination after filtering

Tags: angularjs, pagination

Am using dir-pagination directive for pagination, its working fine but while filtering pagination not getting update

[image: Error-Dir-Pagination]

Below is mycode:

```
     <tbody dir-paginate="booking in bookinglist | itemsPerPage: 30 | orderBy:sortKey:reverse">
        <tr ng-repeat="orders in booking.order | filter: booking_filter | dateRange: startDate : endDate | orderBy:sortKey:reverse">
          <td>{{booking.customer_name}}</td>
          <td>{{orders.order_id}}</td>
          <td>{{orders.service_name}}</td>
          <td>{{orders.employee_name}}</td>
          <td>{{orders.area_name}}</td>
          <td>{{orders.booking_date | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</td>
          <td>{{orders.booking_time}}</td>
          <td>{{orders.status}}</td>
          <td class="g-btn-full-width">
            <button type="button" ng-click="EditBooking(orders._id)" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="DeleteBooking(orders._id)" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="InvoiceGenerate(orders._id)" class="btn btn-warning">Invoice</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <dir-pagination-controls>
        max-size="5"
        direction-links="true"
        boundary-links="true"
    </dir-pagination-controls>
    </div>
```

am stuck with this...Help will be really appreciated

Comment: So when you switch pages the results don't get updated?

Comment: while filtering...based on filter result pagination not getting update

Comment: Don't think this is the issue, but your <dir-pagination-controls> html is closed off so that the attributes are children of the element rather than defined on the element. They probably aren't necessary for the directive to render correctly, but worth cleaning up just to make sure.

Comment: @Nodemon Could you share the `booking_filter` function?

Comment: How is loaded your bookingList ? Asynchronously ? The whole inthe same time or by page ?

Comment: @Nodemon: did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `filter: booking_filter` in your tag where you have put `dir-paginate`

```
<tbody dir-paginate="booking in bookinglist | filter: booking_filter | itemsPerPage: 30 | orderBy:sortKey:reverse">
```

Comment: I was about to answer the same! Hopefully you get the bounty before it expires

Answer (score 0):

Update you booking list object inside your filter function .
Since its two way data binding updating the booking list object might recalculate the filtered pagination.